# Passing strings vs class object as argument to a function

Tags: c#, function, arguments

I need to pass two values to a Function

both these values are in a class Object

i have two options

1. passing the required values as string
2. passing  class object

**Problem:** Class object has many members other than what i want

**Question:** Which is the best option?

Example

This function is using for database query

```
FunctionName(string opt1,string opt2) 
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = this.Connection)
    {
        connection.Execute("select count(*) from table where opt1 = opt1 and opt2 = opt2", new { opt1 = opt1, opt2 = opt2 });
    }
}
```

or

```
FunctionName(className obj)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = this.Connection)
    {
        connection.Execute("select count(*) from table where opt1 = opt1 and opt2 = opt2", new { opt1 = obj.opt1, opt2 = obj.opt2 });
    }
}
```

Function calls are like below

```
 class className {
 public string opt1;
 public string opt2;
 public string opt3;
 public string opt4;// and more
 }

 className obj1

 FunctionName(obj1.opt1,obj1.opt2) Or
 FunctionName(obj1)
```

Comment: What means _"passing as string"_? Use the correct type. The answer is opinion based, all the more because you haven't provided enough informations. What kind of _class_, what kind of method? Is the method an instance method of the class or is it `static`? If not, maybe  the answer is to remove `static`.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code?

Comment: Is there any chance that later you might want more properties from the object? Is there any chance you'd want to call this method with values *not* related to this object? Are you happy for the fact that the method uses those two values to be exposed? If you can give more concrete information, that would really help.

Comment: And where are the two parameters coming from? Are they `string` properties of the class?

Comment: Can you provide  compiling code? Or even better: code with meaningful names for the class, the method and the arguments.Without more context these kind of questions are always opinion based.

Comment: is now question is understandable? Please help

Comment: I think that is based on what you want to achieve. If the function is specifically written to accept two strings no matter who calls that function, then the best option would be to pass on strings instead of class. But if the function is a candidate for change in the future and needs some more parameters, then its better to encapsulate the parameters inside the class and send that class instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 - Passing a new class / structure, specifically designed for the job :)

However, if you only care about efficiency, not security, passing a class reference doesn't depend on how many fields the class has. Passing a class with no fields at all takes exactly as much time as passing a class that has 100 MiB of data. Unless it's a `struct`.

Don't serialize classes to a string and back again just to pass them to a method. That's just a bad idea all around. You lose type safety, it's going to be expensive, and the compiler loses a lot of options to warn you that you're doing something wrong.

Of course, if you just pass the parameters, this needn't matter. This can have some benefits, mostly in ensuring that (as long as you don't use any mutable reference types) you're also going to stay thread-safe, and it limits possible side-effects (e.g. from modifying the passed class - it's not a copy, it's the same instance; again, unless you're passing a `struct`).

Comment: so no efficiency problem with passing a object compared to passing string?

Comment: @TonyStark Exactly. Objects are passed by reference, they're not copied. Even value-types can be passed by reference if needed (using the `ref` keyword). Strings are also classes (although immutable), so they're not any cheaper or more expensive - and you're passing more than one string, so they end up more expensive. Although do note that you can still mostly consider it "free" for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is sort of opinion-based, but I`ll still attempt an answer: My rule of thumb is that if there are few arguments (no more than three - preferably no more than two), then the arguments can be passed directly. Just because that is the simplest solution in most cases.

If you have more than three arguments, you should consider adding a class just for plain clarity. As you point out however, you might not want to pass a class with lots of extra values. If so, you have several options, eg.:

- Create a new class specifically for this purpose, which has exactly the members you need to transfer
- Create a new base class that your main class can inherit from, and move the members you want to expose up into this class. Keep the members you do not want to expose in your original class. Now you can pass the new base class with the stuff you need, and use the sub class internally, with the extra stuff that your function does not need to know about.